How can I automate counting records in multiple Hive tables using parameters in a Hue Workflow?
I have more than 50 tables spread across different databases in Hive, and I need to retrieve the record counts for each table on a daily basis.
To manage this, I already have a table in Hive called p_tables that contains the database names and table names in separate columns:

database_name
tab_name

Rather than writing the SQL query manually for each of these 50+ tables, I am trying to automate the process using Hue. My idea is to create a Hive script that can be parameterized and then used within a Workflow. The script I came up with looks like this:
INSERT INTO db.table
SELECT
    "parameter1" AS `database_name`,
    "parameter2" AS `tab_name`,
    count(*) AS `measurement`,
    CURRENT_DATE AS `p_date`
FROM parameter1.parameter2;

In this script, parameter1 would be the database_name and parameter2 would be the tab_name. The plan is to pass these as parameters in the Workflow.
I attempted to create a Hive script in Hue that uses parameters for the database_name and tab_name values. My expectation was that I could then integrate this script into a Workflow, where I would be able to pass the actual database and table names from the p_tables table as parameters.
However, I'm not sure how to properly set up these parameters in Hue, or if this approach is even feasible. I'm looking for guidance on whether this can be done, and if not, what alternative methods could be used to achieve the same result.
